# Panoply will not create georefernced lat-lon plot for NetCDF data

Tags: netcdf, panoply

I am trying to use panoply to plot and extract time series information from a netcdf obtained from here: https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/sis-water-level-change-timeseries-cmip6?tab=overview. For some reason, Panoply is not offering the option to create a Lon-lat  plot, instead giving the option to create a Lon-Time plot (see screenshot attached).

Anyone know why this is? Ultimately, I want to extract water level time series at a specific location. Screenshot of the dataset details also attached.

[image: option to create lon-lat plot not given]
[image: dataset details]

Answer (score 0):

The metadata indicate that the file includes data at 43119 different locations. The data are *not* lon-lat gridded, so Panoply will not offer to make a lon-lat geo-gridded plot.

That Panoply is offering to make a lon-time or lat-time plot is because it sees a time axis, and also what seem to be lon and lat axes. The metadata suggest that trying to make either of these plot types would probably fail, I suspect with an error message that the lon or lat axis does not have monotonic values.